# is there any way I can create a wordpress template for a post with a specific tag even if I have templates for generic posts?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a tag and using it to show the post in a specific template (For some reason, I cannot use categories).

I create a category slug = test, so, later create `tag-test.php` but the generic `single.php` keeps answering the call.

Is any way to be able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`tag-test.php` will be template used to display posts when the `test`tag archive is displayed. For single posts, the single.php template will be used.

There is no native way to create a single template for tags ( and for that matter any taxonomy ) and have it work out of the box. Single templates only support custom post types, like single-{$post_type}.php.

There is however a filter that we can use to set a custom template for the single posts from a specific tag, called the [`single_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template).

With this mind, create your custom single page template, lets call it single-test.php. This template will be used whenever a single post is tagged with the tag `test`. With this in mind, lets code the function

```
add_filter( 'single_template', function ( $template ) {

    global $post;

    if( has_tag( 'test', $post->ID ) ) {

        $new_template = locate_template( 'single-test.php' );       
        if ( $new_template ) {          

            return $new_template ;      

        }   

    }   

    return $template;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround you could use something like this, however im not sure what would happen if a post was in in more than one tag. Presumably it would get the first tag that post is in either alphabetically or lowest ID.

Add this code to your single.php and add the current content of single.php to whatever you create for ACTUAL_SINGLE_CONTENT.php

```
<?php 
    if ( has_tag('TAG_NAME') ) {
        include(locate_template('TAG_NAME.php')); 
    } 
    elseif ( has_tag('TAGNAME_ONE') ) { 
        include(locate_template('TAG_NAME.php')); 
    } 
    elseif ( has_tag('TAG_NAME_2') ) { 
        include(locate_template('TAG_NAME.php')); 
    } 
    elseif ( has_tag('TAG_NAME_3') ) { 
        include(locate_template('TAG_NAME.php')); 
    } else {
        include(locate_template('ACTUAL_SINGLE_CONTENT.php'));
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: There is a cleaner, much better way to achieve the OP's goal :-)  Check my answer

Comment: Not bad! Go with Pieters answer, mines the long version.
Pieter: Is there a way to pull in the tag name automatically and if a template for it does not exist then use default? (presuming that each post has one tag)

Comment: The code in my answer has a fall back to use the default single.php when no custom template exists. How do you mean automatic. You can retrieve the current post post tags with `wp_get_post_terms()` which is a bit faster than `get_the_tags()`.